# How does Kylo Ren know when to contact this character?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi*, we see that,

> Kylo Ren is contacting Rey in order to get information about Luke (and also maybe turn her to the Dark-side) via some sort of Force-holographic projection.

But how does he know WHEN to contact her? How does he know what is the right time when Luke isn't around?

Is there an explanation given about it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those interactions are not controlled by either Rey or Kylo, they happen on their own to show a sort of connection between the two.

Snoke claims to have been the one arranging the contact, but events after his death make it unclear if this is the case. As it happens at least once after that, it could be that Snoke was working with a connection that was already there, merely set something in motion, or may have just been lying.

In any case, it doesn't appear that either of the parties involved initiate these moments; from their perspective, they just happen on their own, usually in moments of emotional stress. Kylo just happens to use the opportunity to try and get the info out of Rey.

Comment: This answer is pointless. I suggest you reduce the amount of content that's in spoiler tags. People opening the question _know_ it's got spoilers to the last jedi, because it's tagged as such.

Comment: Snoke seems to imply he connects the two of them which then allows them to communicate.  This could easily be closer to giving them a permanent Harry/Voldemort scar connection than actually facilitate and trigger each and every call. That would mean that we can make phone calls long after Mr. Bell passed away. That connection mirrors the luke/leia connection which was highlighted (probably to make the big reveal about parentage more surprising).

Comment: True. But as with most things Snoke, we don't get to know for sure.

Comment: When are the two connected after he dies?

Comment: After the battle on Crait, as everyone is piling into the Falcon. They have one of those moments, punctuated by Rey closing the door.

Comment: @Edlothiad: _"People opening the question know it's got spoilers to the last jedi, because it's tagged as such"_ I don't see any tags in the Hot Network Questions or Related sidebars. Tags are not always displayed alongside question titles.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure be moderate with spoilers, I'm not saying _don't add spoilers_ (I also don't care about people coming from the HNQ or related sidebars, if they're avoiding star wars spoilers don't open something mentioning Kylo Ren). What I was saying was don't cover an _entire_ post in one big spoiler, that's absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 15):

I see a few issues with the premise of the question (spoilers ahead):

1- **Kylo wasn't doing this** - The first time the connection happens, Kylo questions Rey about it, thinking she's behind it somehow. He then mentions "the effort would kill you"; indeed, a similar use of the Force severely weakens Luke at the end of the film, so it makes sense that neither Kylo nor Rey would be behind this feat. Snoke claims he was behind it, which seems likely, given that he is much more powerful than Rey or Kylo. Later on, Rey and Kylo see each other again, but by then they've both experienced great personal/spiritual growth, and are also only a few miles away.

2- **The timing wasn't perfect** - Otherwise Kylo would've known to put a shirt on. Plus, the first time it happened, Luke was right there. Which leads me to my third point:

3- **They didn't need to hide from Luke**- As Rey trains with Luke, she realizes he has closed himself off from the Force. The first time she sees Kylo, she thinks Luke can see him too, but really he can only see the hole she shot through her hut. Only the last time Rey and Kylo meet, when they touch hands, does Luke see Kylo (because Luke has reconnected with the Force).

So, based on these three points, the Force projections aren't perfectly timed, and neither Rey nor Kylo are in charge of when they happen.

Comment: What makes you think Snoke can do it without dying or that a “similar task” killed Luke. Neither of those are confirmed or logically follow each other.

Comment: Luke set up two-way visual and auditory communication across vast distances, it's a very similar effect as what happened between Rey and Kylo. Plus out-of-universe what Luke did wouldn't have made any sense if we hadn't seen Rey and Kylo doing it earlier in the film. As for Snoke, it's not so much that it's obvious he'd survive, more that he's the most powerful Force-sensitive we know of, so if anyone can do it it'd be him.

Comment: Nothing of what you just said means it caused Luke’s death. Do we know he’s the most powerful force sensitive? Luke scoured the galaxy learning. I feel like you’ve turned assumptions into fact, unless you can prove me wrong with evidence of course

Comment: I mean, he didn't die of a broken heart. And he was otherwise a perfectly healthy man in his 50s. I guess you could say he just gave up on life but that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Either way, I've now edited to address your concerns.

Comment: "I guess you could say he just gave up on life but that doesn't really make sense to me."  Well, that is how his mother died.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the effort of his long-distance show did lead to his death. This was foreshadowed earlier in the film, when Kylo points out that Rey couldn't be the one making contact, as it would kill her. In Luke's case,  it was a death he chose and was prepared for. He didn't "give up"; his show and subsequent death were calculated.

Comment: @Irishpanda the argument tends to be “he was sprawled across the rock” no he wasn’t, he was tired from it, then begins to meditate and gives himself to the force. He doesn’t just die, he clearly gives himself to the force. We’ve seen Jedi simply die,they don’t all just ghost away.

Comment: In any case, the move was deliberate. He knew the strain would get him (remember the foreshadowing scene); when he pulled himself up on the rock, he was simply looking out at the double sunset as he was dying. Becoming one with the Force was just part of that process.

Comment: The double sunset was a nice callback to the very first scene where we see Luke in _A New Hope_.